# Получить результат запроса с json в Where

Tags: php

Как в запросе в and можно указать колонку с json.
У менять есть талица продукции. В ней колонка category_id вида {"id_cat":[1,2,3,4]}
Мне нужно составить запрос на получение продукции по категории. Т.е. подставить id категории в запрос.

Например:

```html
$db->getAll('SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1 AND JSON_CONTAINS(category_id, 2)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо третьим параметром указать путь к значению внутри json объекта

```
$db->getAll('SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1 AND JSON_CONTAINS(category_id, 2, '$.id_cat')');
```